# Intermittent authorization failure on publish

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am seeing an odd intermittent authorization failure on publish. My publisher is running on App Engine Standard (Python). Because of that, I am using the "old" python client library. So the code looks like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
build('pubsub','v1').projects().topics().publish(topic=topic,body=body).execute()
```

This works just fine. The identity gets picked up and everything is authenticated. However, again intermittently, it will stop working and I get 403 forbidden errors. Then later it will start working again (even with the same topic and body). In the meantime, no code changes, no deployments.

I have had to wrap the publish to catch this error, throw it on a task queue and have the request repeat with decaying frequency until it finally starts working again a few hours later. This is OK in the very short term, but obviously this will not work for us.

To summarize, this is on the publish side, GAE Standard ... it works, then stops working, then works again.
Thanks for any insight or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, of course, that in fact there were deployments when I wasn't aware. So I thought, "no code change - no deployments", but there were deployments. And the issue was that the person making these deployments had an old library (or other dependency) for `google_api_python_client`. Once corrected, pubsub is working just fine.

Comment: Hi @Jay, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the nudge. I had intended to accept my own answer - lost track of it.